# Número de filas afectadas en postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Cuando realizo un `insert`, `update` o `delete` dentro de una función en `postgresql` desearía obtener el número de filas afectadas para que en el Lenguaje de Programación verificar si se ejecuto correctamente la `query`.

En `MySQL` existe `@@identity` cuando hay auto incrementables y `row_count()` filas afectadas, quiero lo mismo pero en `postgresql`.

Comment: Por cierto que no especificas el _"Lenguaje de Programación"_, pero en Python, por ejemplo, el protocolo DBAPI 2.0 definido en el PEP-0249, incluye el atributo [`.rowcount()`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount) para los cursores, que permiten exactamente lo que pides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma de obtener la cantidad de columnas afectadas dentro de una funcion o store procedure es: ([Mas info.](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/57097.18732.qm@web65716.mail.ac4.yahoo.com#57097.18732.qm@web65716.mail.ac4.yahoo.com))

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS my_var = ROW_COUNT;
```

Aunque también puede hacerlo por medio de la [RETURNING](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-insert.html), que hace que el insert retorne un conjunto de datos igual que lo hace select.

```
WITH filas AS (
    INSERT INTO tabla
        (clave, datos)
    VALUES
        (DEFAULT, 'dato fila 1'),
        (DEFAULT, 'dato fila 2')
    RETURNING clave
)
SELECT count(*) FROM filas;
```

Esto obtiene el total de filas afectadas. Puedes usarlo también para obtener las columnas auto incrementales, pero si no te gusta, hay otra mas natural forma de hacerlo:

Como los campos autoincrementales se implementan con secuencias en PostgreSQL, hay unas funciones que lo manejan todo:

`currval` y `lastval`, son las opciones, pero dependiendo el caso pudes usar una u otra. Chequea la [documentación](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html).

```
INSERT INTO tabla (datos) VALUES ('dato 3');
SELECT lastval() INTO ultimoId
```

## Como obtenerlo desde la aplicación:

Suponiendo que tienes una función que hace varias cosas y quieres reportarlas todas puedes crear un `TYPE` que tenga un campo para cada valor a retornar. Durante la ejecución de la función, cargas los valores a retornar y luego 
haces que tu función retorne dicho tipo, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
CREATE TYPE result_mi_funcion (agregadas int, borradas int, clave_registro bigint);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mi_funcion(name text) 
RETURNS result_mi_funcion 
AS 
$$

DECLARE
  resultados result_mi_funcion;

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tabla (campos) VALUES ( ... );

  GET DIAGNOSTICS resultados.agregadas = ROW_COUNT;

  DELETE FROM table WHERE ....;

  GET DIAGNOSTICS resultados.borradas = ROW_COUNT;

  INSERT INTO registro (...) ... ;

  SELECT lastval() INTO resultados.clave_registro;

  RETURN resultados;

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Finalmente desde la aplicación la funciona retornara un solo registro con la estructura del `TYPE` que creaste.

Únicamente deberás leer los valores de las columnas.

Answer (score 0):

Primero creamos una tabla de prueba con dos columnas: `id` y `mensaje`. Luego insertamos 4 filas.

```
CREATE TABLE mensajes(
  id serial primary key,
  mensaje text not null
);

INSERT INTO mensajes (mensaje) VALUES ('Hola mundo!');
INSERT INTO mensajes (mensaje) VALUES ('Hola mundo!');
INSERT INTO mensajes (mensaje) VALUES ('Hola mundo!');
INSERT INTO mensajes (mensaje) VALUES ('Hola mundo!');
```

Ahora actualizamos las filas cuyo con `id` impar. El resultado del `UPDATE` lo guardamos en la variable `resultadoUpdate` haciendo uso de [wCTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-with.html). `RETURNING` nos permite devolver un valor por cada columna que ha sido modificada, más información [aquí](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-update.html).

```
WITH resultadoUpdate AS (
  UPDATE mensajes
  SET
    mensaje = 'Adios mundo!'
  WHERE id%2 = 0
  RETURNING id
) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM resultadoUpdate AS filasAfectadas;

RAISE NOTICE '% han sido modificadas.', filasAfectadas;
```

El número de filas alteradas se encuentra almacenado ahora en la variable `filasAfectadas`.

Si quieres ver este ejemplo funcionando, he creado un `SQLFiddle` aquí: [sqlfiddle.com/#!15/89a3e/20](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/89a3e/20)

Comment: Gracias me sirvió mucho.